# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Web Portal show white screen/blank display when accessed via Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, reporting-services, windows-authentication, azure-application-gateway

I have SSRS installed on an Azure Virtual Machine and I need to access the SSRS Web Portal publicly via Azure Application Gateway. I have configured the domain name with SSL certificate on the gateway for my VM. Backend Health status is healthy. Upon access to the web portal, a login prompt displays (windows authentication). After inputting
 the credentials, I only get a white screen on my Google chrome and Microsoft Edge.

I can successfully access the web portal locally on the Virtual Machine and also via the Public IP of the VM as well as via the Azure domain name of the VM.

I have tried to remove the SSL certificate and use the application gateway's frontend IP so I'm connecting to the VM Web Portal via HTTP but I still get the white screen after I login. I have allowed the specific ports on my network security group and disabled the firewall on my VM but there shouldn't be a problem on this since I am able to reach the login prompt of my ssrs web portal. It seems that there is an issue upon authentication.

Comment: Is there any message in the backend health of your application gateway?

Comment: Hi nancy, tjhank you for noticing my question.. since the status of my backend health is healthy, it just says success on the details